# Show value on page load in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to display a value when page is loaded.

My code is,

```
$.getJSON("http://***.com/Test/testnew.php", function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (i, sample) {
        var dd = data.sample;
        alert(dd);
        var count = dd,
            pad = '00000';
        $('#support_num').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var ctxt = '' + count;
            $('p').text(pad.substr(0, pad.length - ctxt.length) + ctxt);
        });
    });
});
```

Here the value is displayed onclick of a button. But i want it on page load.

Comment: So just put the code out of the click callback.

Comment: _"Here the value is displayed onclick of a button"_ - Do you mean that _all_ of the above code is currently called from some button's click handler? Or are you talking about the #support_num element that has a click handler assigned in that code? (Speaking of which, _don't_ call `$('#support_num').click(...` inside the `$.each()` statement, you're creating multiple duplicate handlers on the same element, all of which update the content of all p elements on the page.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a modified version of your code that runs when the page loads instead of on the click:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("http://www.sample.com/Test/testnew.php",function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i, sample) {
            var count = data.sample + "";
            var pad = '00000';
            $('p').text(pad.substr(0, pad.length - count.length) + count);
        });
    });
});
```

The part of this code that doesn't make sense is running the same code multiple times in the `$.each()` loop.  That is probably not doing what you want, but I left it that way because you haven't said how it's really supposed to handle multiple pieces of data in the response.

Comment: thank you so much...I know my question is so silly..itz just am very new to this

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by putting your function in Document.Ready like

By doing this ur function will be called when the DOM is loaded, and u will get the alert.

```
enter code here
  $(document).ready(function(){
      // Your code goes here.
  });
```